# When I fill a data frame using df.append, columns I put a 0 get stored as float instead of integer

Tags: python

I have a loop that uses  `df.append`, to fill a data frame. The columns that are filled with a zero or one get displayed as a float when I print the DF how can I store them as integers?

```
for index, row in df_from.iterrows():
    print(row)
    price=row["Close"]
    open=row["Open"]
    close=row["Close"]
    smallest=row["Low"]
    biggest=row["High"]
    bvol=row["Volume"]
    svol=0
    isvalid=1
    time=pes
    # i put a 1 in isvalis column, 
    s={'Price' : price ,'Time' : time ,'open' : open, 'close' : close, 'smallest': smallest, 'biggest': biggest, 'bvol' : bvol, 'svol': svol, 'isvalid' : 1, 'sell1' : 0,'vol1' :0,'id1':0, 'sell2' : 0,'vol2' :0,'id2':0 , 'sell3' : 0,'vol3' :0,'id3':0 ,'dummy1' : 0,'dummy2' : 0,'dummy3' :0 }

    df=df.append( s,  ignore_index=True)
    pes=pes+1
print(df)
```

Comment: how do you initialize df? please give an example

Comment: This really depends on the `dtypes` of each column/element. Unless they are `object` (I think), you don't have the ability to change them.

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding a dictionary, and in that dictionary, you have some new column, the pandas default behavior is to add integer as a float.

one workaround can be, add all the columns you want, and at the end convert datatype to most suitable by `convert_dtypes()`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2.4],"b":[2,3]})
df.dtypes
```

add new column "cnew"

```
my_map={"a":1,"b":2,"cnew":1}
df=df.append(my_map,ignore_index=True)
#df['cnew'] = df.cnew.astype('Int64') ==> this would also work
df.head(10)
```

convert datatype:

```
df=df.convert_dtypes()
# integer operation works well too!
df.groupby(['a']).sum()
```

output:
[the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZvtB.png)